# Errors using FindRoot on slow numerical function

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, warning-messages

I would like to find the solution of an equation containing a slow function

```
FindRoot[func[x, onsideS, hoppingS, 0.01] - (1/E) == 0, {x, 1,10}]
```

for different values of `onsideS` and `hoppingS`. `func` is given by

```
func[tau_?NumericQ, onsideS_?NumericQ, hoppingS_?NumericQ, eta_?NumericQ] := 
    func[tau, onsideS, hoppingS, eta] =
    Min[Exp[eta*tau]*Abs[NIntegrate[Exp[-I*x*tau]*(1/(2 Pi))*((1/(x - onsideS + I*eta)) 
    + ((1/(x - onsideS + I*eta))^2)*(hoppingS^2)*localGF[x,eta]*
    (1/(1 - (hoppingS^2) * (1/(x - onsideS + I*eta))*localGF[x, eta]))), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},  
    Method -> {"LevinRule", "Kernel" -> Exp[-I*x*tau]}], 1]
```

with

```
localGF[energy_?NumericQ, eta_?NumericQ] := localGF[energy, eta] =  
    NIntegrate[ldos[x]/(energy - x + I*eta), {x, -hbw, hbw}, 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 25,"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
ldos[energy_?NumericQ] := (1/(Pi))*Sqrt[1 - (energy/2)^2]
hbw = 2;
```

However `Mathematica` always returns a bunch of error messages containing of

> NIntegrate: Integrand is not a Levin function
>
> FindRoot: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations

and `FindRoot` never gives a valid result, even though calling `func` manually returns something useful. The same happens when trying to `Plot` this function. I tried using `NSolve` aswell

```
NSolve[func[x, onsideS, hoppingS, 0.01] - 1/E == 0, x, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

and it works atleast for certain values (i.e. `onsideS = 0` and `hoppingS = 1`) quite fast, but evaluation time increases very quickly when going to other values (i.e. `onsideS = 0` and `hoppingS = 0.05`).

Why does this happen and how could I fix this?

Comment: what value have `hbw`?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Sorry, I forgot adding it into the question. `hbw = 2;`

Comment: The error message you get suggests that `localGF` has not been passed into the `FindRoot` properly, I can't see why immediately though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but some hints.

First, do as much integrations, you can, analytically.

```
hbw = 2;

ldos[energy_] = (1/(Pi))*Sqrt[1 - (energy/2)^2] // Simplify;

localGF[energy_, eta_] = 
   Integrate[ldos[x]/(energy - x + I*eta), {x, -hbw, hbw}, 
         Assumptions -> eta > 0 && energy \[Element] Reals]

(*   -(1/2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4/(energy + I eta)^2]) (energy + I eta)   *)
```

Then regard the integrand for NIntegrate at different parameters.

```
integrand1[tau_, onsideS_, hoppingS_, eta_, x_] = 
    Exp[-I*x*tau]*(1/(2 Pi))*((1/(x - onsideS + 
     I*eta)) + ((1/(x - onsideS + I*eta))^2)*(hoppingS^2)*
    localGF[x, 
     eta]*(1/(1 - (hoppingS^2)*(1/(x - onsideS + I*eta))*
       localGF[x, eta]))) // Simplify;

Manipulate[
  int = integrand1[tau, onsideS, hoppingS, 1/100, x]; {Plot[
   Re@int, {x, -10, 10}], Plot[Im@int, {x, -10, 10}]}, {tau, 1, 
   10}, {onsideS, 0, 4}, {hoppingS, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

For some parameter combinations, NIntegrate works quite good

```
NIntegrate[integrand1[1, 0, 1, 1/100, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*   2.77556*10^-17 - 0.57145 I   *)

NIntegrate[integrand1[2, 0, 1, 1/100, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*   0. + 0.0321347 I   *)
```

For others, like shown in picture, there is a non integrable singularity at zero or other x-values, you have to use Method -> "PrincipalValue" an explicitly give the x-value of it in integration range.

```
NIntegrate[integrand1[1, 0, 0, 1/100, x], {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity},
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

(*   0. - 0.99005 I   *)
```

For other parameter values, integral failes to converge.

```
NIntegrate[
  integrand1[1, 0, 2/10, 1/100, x], {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

It's a tricky job to further examine integrand behavior and positions of singularities.